# Multiple domains pointing to one server. Using a rewrite rule to set preferred domain

Tags: c#, web-config, iis-8

I just launched a new website for a client. As part of the new launch I want to try and sort out their domains. Currently they have 3 domains all pointing to the same server which is bad when it comes to SEO. Unfortunately, I do not have direct access to the IIS configuration of the server as it is with a hosting provider but I would like to ensure that if a user comes in on two of the domains they are redirected to what we consider the main domain.

So far I have the following setup:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^maindomain.dk$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^otherdomain1.dk$"  />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^otherdomain2.dk$"  />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.maindomain.dk/{R:0}"
        redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
     </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I only want Google to register my maindomain.dk. Whilst I'm at it, I only ever want it to use the www.maindomain.dk version of this domain. However, the script above does not work.

When I navigate to otherdomain1.dk it simply goes to that URL. If I navigate to otherdomain2.dk it goes to that URL. The maindomain.dk exhibits the correct behaviour. What do I need to change to get this to work?

Comment: Hey. I just wondered if the answer worked for you. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the conditions' logical grouping to be "match any"

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
```

Also, you should fix your patterns to escape the dots

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^maindomain\.dk$" />
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^otherdomain1\.dk$"  />
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^otherdomain2\.dk$"  />
```